# converting nsdictionary to xml format in iphone

Tags: iphone

I'am able to display the data in nsdictionary using this code

```
NSString *testXMLString = @"<items><item id=\"0001\" type=\"donut\"><name>Cake</name><ppu>0.55</ppu><batters><batter id=\"1001\">Regular</batter><batter id=\"1002\">Chocolate</batter><batter id=\"1003\">Blueberry</batter></batters><topping id=\"5001\">None</topping><topping id=\"5002\">Glazed</topping><topping id=\"5005\">Sugar</topping></item></items>";
    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:testXMLString error:&parseError];
    NSLog(@"%@", xmlDictionary);
```

and the output is

```
items =     {
        item =         {
            batters =             {
                batter =                 (
                                        {
                        id = 1001;
                        text = Regular;
                    },
                                        {
                        id = 1002;
                        text = Chocolate;
                    },
                                        {
                        id = 1003;
                        text = Blueberry;
                    }
                );
            };
            id = 0001;
            name =             {
                text = Cake;
            };
            ppu =             {
                text = "0.55";
            };
            topping =             (
                                {
                    id = 5001;
                    text = None;
                },
                                {
                    id = 5002;
                    text = Glazed;
                },
                                {
                    id = 5005;
                    text = Sugar;
                }
            );
            type = donut;
        };
    }; }
```

Can anyone please help me how to convert this dictionary into a xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NSPropertyListSerialization` class should be able to do this for you.